# How to restore the PLSQL Developer window?

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I closed the window that sees all tables, procedures, packages, users, etc.

I couldn't find where to restore the windows, can someone help?

I am using version 14.0.1.1965

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to toggle `Object Browser` in `Tools` window in order to see the window displaying tables, procedures etc. Moreover, the `Window List` located at the left bottom corner is also activated from the same menu also.

This picture is taken from the version `11.0.2.1766` :

[image]